# Bulma hoverable dropdown doesn't show

Tags: javascript, html, dropdown, bulma

js computes the structure below, i need a dropdown when the button is hovered whereas onclick should trigger the form submit.
[image]

nothing happens when i hover the button area. Is it because of is-active missing?

Answer (score 1):

In [Bulma's official docs about the dropdown menu](https://bulma.io/documentation/components/dropdown/#hoverable-or-toggable), the example's indent can be confusing.
The "dropdown-menu" 'div' is a childnode of the main dropdown 'div'.

```
<div class="dropdown is-hoverable">
  <div class="dropdown-trigger">
    <button class="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-controls="dropdown-menu4">
      <span>Hover me</span>
      <span class="icon is-small">
        <i class="fas fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" id="dropdown-menu4" role="menu">
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <div class="dropdown-item">
        <p>You can insert <strong>any type of content</strong> within the dropdown menu.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```